# PHP, PDO. How do I get the default fetch mode?

Tags: php, pdo

It is possible to set the default fetch mode using:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, $fetch_mode);
```

Consider such a function:

```
<?php

function do_something($fetch_mode = /* default fetch mode */){
  // Do something
}

?>
```

Here I need to GET the default fetch mode. How do I get it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getattribute.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE);
```

That gives you an int and you can do the mapping yourself using the list provided in the manual.

Comment: Such an attribute is not listed there. Nevertheless it works! Thank you

Comment: Then that's a great opportunity for you to try all the different modes and create a table for them with their corresponding integers and provide that list in a comment on the manual  and help the future readers